A play where a corpse keeps growing and growing from one scene to the next one
I actually went to a theater to watch this play, at the insistence of my girlfriend at that time. So it was about 50 years ago. It was in French, and most probably the original, not a translation.
What I remember best about it is that I did not like it at all. Besides that and what I put in the title I remember almost nothing.
It was mostly a "huis clos", as we say in French, a few people in a closed space, but not the play with this title by Sartre. IIRC, just a married couple, plus a corpse of which one sees only part of the legs, which increase in size from one scene to the next one.
I use the tag "horror" to mean fantasy since it is definitely not SF. But I found it more boring than frightening. Well, horribly boring, maybe...

I thought this sounded like Ionesco, and a quick Google confirms that it is his play Amédée, or How to Get Rid of It.
From Wikipedia:

The premise of the play is revealed in the opening scene with a growing corpse. Amédée and Madeleine, the two main characters, are grotesque and dehumanized as they consider their options for disposing of the corpse.


That was fast. I had totally forgotten it was by Ionesco. I should have known. Very long ago I tried to read "La Cantatrice Chauve" and closed it at the third or fourth page.... No other attempt since then.

Is it a fantasy though?

With a corpse that keeps increasing in size up to filling the entire apartment ? I'd say it is fantasy. Boring, but fantasy. Towards the end one just sees the shoes, filling the entire back side of the scene.
